# How to iterate through a series of Classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, while-loop

I have a series of elements, all of the same class.

```
<img class="clicker" src="#"/>
<img class="clicker" src="#"/>
<img class="clicker" src="#"/>
```

I want to be able to iterate through these classes and alert each of their `src` attributes to the user using jQuery.

```
var one = $('.clicker').attr('src');
    alert(one);
    while($('.clicker').next().length){
        ...
        ...
    alert(next src);
    }
```

I'm not really sure how to write this `while` loop, or if there is something better to use than `while` in this instance. How should I do this?

Comment: FYI: all the answers below use `$(this).attr('src')` ... which is jQuery longhand for `this.src` (sort of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3sk662c/)

```
$('.clicker').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); // used id instead of src as src doesn't have any value other than #
});
```

Comment: FYI: `src !== id`

Comment: Accepting this one purely because you have the least amount of points, but they all work. Can't believe I didn't know this

Answer (score 2):

You need the following:

```
$(".clicker").each( function() {
  alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over

```js
$('img.clicker').each(function(i, v) {
  alert($(this).attr('src'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="clicker" src="#" />
<img class="clicker" src="#" />
<img class="clicker" src="#" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Fairly simple as follows

```
$(".clicker").each( () =>{
  //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$( ".clicker" ).each(function() {
      console.log( $( this ).attr('src') );
    });
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/each/)